# Unable to Get rid of php7.2 which is blocking installation of php8.0

Tags: ubuntu-20.04, php-7.2, php-8

I have a challenge in getting rid of php7.2.2 to pave way for php8.0 on my machine. I have tried to with a number of suggested solutions but still don't understand why php7.2.2 still shows up when i run `php -v` yet on trying to purge that specific php version the, it's not found. I have even tried to restart my pc to see if the changes would be effective but not. Please see the screenshot attached below.

[image: commands illustrated in the screenshot]

First, I started By trying to remove php7.2.2 using the following commands:-
sudo apt-get --purge auto-remove php7.2.2

Second, Interactive switching mode

`sudo update-alternatives --config php`
`sudo update-alternatives --config phar`
`sudo update-alternatives --config phar.phar`

Third, I tried Manual Switching
From PHP 7.2 => PHP 8.0

Default PHP 7.2 is set on the system and I had to switch to PHP 8.0.
Apache:

`$ sudo a2dismod php7.2`
`$ sudo a2enmod php8.0`
`$ sudo service apache2 restart`

Have also tried, Command Line:

`$ sudo update-alternatives --set php /usr/bin/php8.0`
`$ sudo update-alternatives --set phar /usr/bin/phar8.0`
`$ sudo update-alternatives --set phar.phar /usr/bin/phar.phar8.0`

Comment: Please share more details, like the error message in text form and your next attempts to resolve this problem. `dpkg -l ` could show you which packages are still installed, and usually they are named `php7.2-cli` and not `php7.2.2`

Comment: It's not showing any error in all these commands. The problem i'm having is getting the older version of php which i removed. New version of php is confirmed from the browser using phpInfo(), while from cli php -v command still display the older version.

Comment: Then why not remove PHP 7.2 completely if you don't want to use it anymore?

Comment: That's is the first thing i tried to do if look at my problem description above but haven't managed to remove it.

Comment: What else did you try? I've provided the name of the package that could be removed in my first comment, along with a command that could help you to find the proper package name

Comment: It doesn't remove the package. Please could be available for a few minutes I give you remote control of my machine you try to assist.

Comment: No, thanks. Please be aware that the message "Couldn't find any package" is pretty obvious if you repeatedly try to use a different package name than that recommended to use in the first comment

Comment: I had to delete every package, files and folders that was related to php on the machine, then re-installed php 8 afresh which now work fine. Thanks.